# How can I interact with a message that chrome sends me using python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[This is it and I want to make my program press add extension,but I can't see that button in the page source so I pretty much don't know how to interact with it using selenium.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlhEQ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to automate is not a web element therefore you need different tools, for example for Windows you can use https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/.